# Did the Bakers torture children?

Tags: resident-evil, resident-evil-7

During one scene while attempting to outwit Lucas, after Ethan swears at him, Lucas has the following line:

> **Lucas**: Ethan, language. There are children in the building! Somewhere. I think. I’m not sure anymore.

Once you've beaten the game, this ends up having an excellent double meaning as a bit of foreshadowing:

> Eveline is in the house, but it's anyone's guess whether she truly counts as a "child" anymore.

But it also left me curious about the 'straightforward' meaning of it, as when he says it, it's pretty obviously intended to come off as a Lucas-typical cruel joke about there being children among his family's victims. Has the Baker family actually made victims out of any children? I don't remember seeing evidence of it, but if there is some I'm guessing it'd be more subtle or buried in the lore.